# swift my read more/less button doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to read more/less functionality to me about label but it doesn't work
here my code is

```
@IBAction func onClickReadMore(_ sender: Any) {
        if isLabelAtMaxHeight {
            readMore.setTitle("Read more", for: .normal)
            isLabelAtMaxHeight = false
            lblHeight.constant = 70
            
        }
        else {
            readMore.setTitle("Read less", for: .normal)
            isLabelAtMaxHeight = true 
            lblHeight.constant = getLabelHeight(text: about.text!, width: userPost.bounds.width, font: about.font)
        }
    }
    func getLabelHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        about.frame.size.width = width
        about.font = font
        about.numberOfLines = 0
        about.text = text
        about.sizeToFit()
        
        return about.frame.size.height
    }





I want to increase the number of lines if text.count > 200
```

but when i click on read more button my application crashed

Comment: What is the error what you get ?

Comment: Crash? You should have an error output in console, which is... ?

Comment: The only vulnerable statement I see that can lead to crash is `about.text!`, did your label/textfield had no text when you tapped on read more?, about.text ?? "" should take care of crash or `if let text = about.text {` as well

Comment: The reason for the crash is    "reason: '-[UILabel setConstant:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc5cc32f60'"

Comment: @πter,@Sandeep Bhandari,@ Larme